# Find the residue of the following number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find the residue  :
\begin{equation}
1^{965}+2^{965}+...+2018^{965}
 \equiv x\ (\textrm{mod}\ 2021), x=?
\end{equation}
My attempt so far:
\begin{equation}
\varphi(965)=\varphi(5)\varphi(193)=768.
\end{equation}
But from Euler theorem applied for all numbers coprime with both 5 and 193 we have:\begin{equation} \Rightarrow\ 2^{768}\equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 2021) \Rightarrow\ 2^{965}\equiv 2^{197}\ (\textrm{mod}\ 2021).
\end{equation}
In the same fashion we get that \begin{equation}
3^{965}\equiv 3^{197}\ (\textrm{mod}\ 2021).
\end{equation}
Unfortunatelly this does not seem to work. Any ideas how to start?

Comment: For Euler's theorem, you don't want the totient of the exponent, you want the totient of the modulus: $\varphi(2015)=1440$. So $a^{1440}\equiv 1$, for coprime $a$. Which, admittedly, doesn't help all that much.

Comment: Would it be easier if the sum went up to $2020^{965}$?

Comment: @Arthur:  did you mean $\phi(2021)=1932$ when you typed $\phi(2015)=1440?$  Your first clause was an important point for OP, though

Comment: Suggest you look at [Carmichael's reduced totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(2021)=\text{lcm}(\lambda(43),\lambda(47)) = \text{lcm}(42,46) = 966$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes. For some reason I had 2015 in my head.

Comment: Exploit **reflection symmetry** (modular negation) as explained in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 2):

I think with solving mod equivalences, people are afraid of "dirty solutions". But I think just bashing it out works just fine.

Note that $$x^{2p+1}+(-x)^{2p+1}=(x+-x)(x^{2p})=0$$So, the sum is equal to $$1^{965}+2^{965}\bmod{2021}\to1+2^{965}\bmod{2021}$$Note that $2^{11}=2048$, so $2^{11}\equiv3^3\bmod{2021}$

Can you solve from here?

Comment: Additionally, $2^{2\cdot 965+2}\equiv 1$, so we know that $(2(x-1))^2\equiv 1$, i.e., $2(x-1)$ can only by $\equiv \pm1$, which means $x-1\equiv \pm 1010$

Comment: $(+1)$; or $2^{966}\equiv1\bmod2021$ by Euler, so $2^{965}\equiv 2^{-1}\equiv\dfrac{2021+1}2\bmod2021$

Comment: @Don Thousand I am sorry but the first two lines are impossible for me to follow. The first line is trivial and I cannot see how  did you use it.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: @BillDubuque Mirror my comment from the other question